# Error when deploying laravel app to google app engine

Tags: php, laravel, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I find this error when I do the according to [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-flexible)

```
ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker@sha256:9ab43021cda6dda1507c00d9c0489829515637bebbc9e9e3f99a24f253abc768"
failed: exit status 1
```

---

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Cloud build failed. Check logs at 
https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/builds/5b9ce7e4-eb2e-4d3f-8c6c-ddf503bde123?project=friendlychat-ed239
Failure status: UNKNOWN: Error Response: [2] Build failed; check build logs for details
```

Relevant part of log is:

```
Step #1: [0mDiscovered Package: fideloper/proxy 
Step #1: Discovered Package: laravel/tinker 
Step #1: Package manifest generated successfully. 
Step #1: [91m> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postInstall 
Step #1: [0m[91m> php artisan cache:clear 
Step #1: [0m[91m[13-Feb-2018 16:31:05 UTC] [2018-02-13 16:31:05] 
production.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory 
{"exception":"[object] (PDOException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory at /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:67)"} [] 
Step #1: [0m[91m[13-Feb-2018 16:31:05 UTC] [2018-02-13 16:31:05] production.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: delete from `cache`) {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: delete from `cache`) at /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664, PDOException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory at /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:67)"} [] 
Step #1: [0m Step #1: In Connection.php line 664: 
Step #1:  Step #1: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: delete from `cache`)  
Step #1:  Step #1:  Step #1: In Connector.php line 67: 
Step #1:  Step #1: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory  
Step #1:  Step #1:  Step #1: [91mScript php artisan cache:clear handling the post-install-cmd event returned with error code 1 
Step #1: The command '/bin/sh -c /build-scripts/composer.sh' returned a non-zero code: 1 
Finished Step #1 ERROR ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker@sha256:9ab43021cda6dda1507c00d9c0489829515637bebbc9e9e3f99a24f253abc768" 
failed: exit status 1 Step #1: [0m
```

How to fix it?

Comment: i had a problem earlier try  "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize",
            "chmod -R 755 bootstrap\/cache"

Answer (score 4):

I also facing the same problem in last few days ago by following same link that you mentioned https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-flexible. Now I can deploy successfully by replacing:

```
post-install-cmd": [
"chmod -R 755 bootstrap\/cache",
"php artisan cache:clear" ]
```

with

```
"post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "php artisan optimize",
        "chmod -R 755 bootstrap\/cache" ]
```

in composer.json

This is only **removing php artisan cache:clear** command that giving error.

I got this info from https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/issues/371

If it still cannot solve problem, you can comment out **SESSION_DRIVER: database** in app.yaml and test again (In my case, I do not need this).
You also need to check that you already enable SQL API or not.
Good luck~

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your [CloudSQL API is enabled](https://console.cloud.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=sqladmin)
If that doesn't work, check out [this thread](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/issues/371) for other possible ways to fix the problem.  As mentioned in the comment above, an easy way to solve this is to just use `SESSION_DRIVER: cookie` instead, and bypass database sessions all together if you don't need them.